# How to capture All requests in jmeter when there are 1000 of different URL query strings in Web application

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I have a Web app that has 7 modules and each module has 1000 of search filters and data vary according to search filter.
I need to perform Load test using Jmeter I record the script using blaze meter but to check each and every search filter it is very time taking to select search filters and record and perform load test.
Is there any way that All search filters and URL query strings can be loaded in jmeter?

Need solutions for Web App load test having 1000s of filters.
what is the standard to perform load test? only on Base URL or each and every url with different filters?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what do you mean by "filters" and how they're implemented on [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) level.

If it's a matter of URL [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) - you can dump your filters into a [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and use JMeter's [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) so each virtual user would read next "filter" from the CSV file on each iteration amending [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler path or parameters with the data from the CSV file.

Comment: Filter means Search Filter Like in application i have different search filter Example is 
Country, City, School. If you select any of search filter it appends in URL. 
And it makes 1000s of URL under one module.

Comment: Yes right it is a matter of query String. @Dmitri T